# How to generate same wallet address in both BEP20 and ERC20 using web3

Tags: blockchain, web3js, erc20, ether, bep20

How to generate same wallet address(same public key) in both BEP20(Binance Smart Chain) and ERC20(Ethereum) using web3?

I want to use one single key pair for both networks. I can see some exchange website provide same wallet address for both networks.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an address by using

```js
web3.eth.accounts.create();
```